# Test::double don't take the method

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, mockery

I got an static method on my DeveloperTinker, but, when i run it, appear

> [BadMethodCallException]
>     Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::firstName()

This is my code

```
 $mockUser = Mockery::mock('User');
 $mockUser -> shouldReceive("firstName")->with('1')->andReturn('Luis');
 Test::double('User', ["firstName" => $mockUser]);
 $userOP = User::firstName('user-51e06817-c03c822b');
 $this->info($userOP->firstName('1'));
 return;`
```

Comment: Don't mock models, you have factories... mocking stuff is so 2015 time.

Comment: I need to do with mock because i'm working with Laravel 4.2